# Emtpy Space at Bottom UI (C#, UWP)

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp

I have a question about my UWP UI ... why is there a space at the bottom, when i launch the app?

```
<Page
  Background="DarkMagenta" Height="800" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column ="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Background="#1f3d7a"/>
    <Border Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Aquamarine"/>
    <Border Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Beige"/>
    <Border Grid.Column ="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="Coral"/>
    <Border Grid.Column ="3" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightCyan"/>
    <Border Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="Pink"/>
    <Border Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="2" Background="Gold"/>
    <Border Grid.Column ="2" Grid.Row="2" Background="LightGray"/>
    <Border Grid.Column ="3" Grid.Row="2" Background="Olive"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

I thought, the whole screen should be filled with a grid? But the space is also not DarkMagenta.

Here is the picture:

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYWN7.png)

Comment: That's because you have set the `VerticalAlignment` of the `Page` to top. Set it as `stretch`, and I think that will do it.

Comment: Different, but not better with `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`: https://i.imgur.com/bqKcDGn.png Now i have space at the top and the bottom :D

Comment: Get rid of the height (800) on the page as well as the alignment.  The Grid will fill all available space naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint of the page height of 800 is conflicting with stretch when the actual window height is over 800 is my guess.  It works as I believe you are expecting if you remove the height and alignment.  The page alignment interferes with the Grid's natural tendency to fill its container (assuming you do not constrain it with height or width or align it)

```
<Page
    x:Class="App5.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App5"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="DarkMagenta">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column ="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Background="#1f3d7a"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Aquamarine"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Beige"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="Coral"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="3" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightCyan"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="Pink"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="1" Grid.Row="2" Background="Gold"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="2" Grid.Row="2" Background="LightGray"/>
        <Border Grid.Column ="3" Grid.Row="2" Background="Olive"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

[image]